# Python: merge Nested Dictionary into one JSON

Tags: python, json

How to merge strings from the yield generator of JSON into one JSON?

I have got Nested Dictionary by yield generator, and I aim to have one JSON file.

I have the output of these correct strings of nested dictionary.

```json
{"domain.com": {"Chrome": "19362.344607264396"}}
{"domain.com": {"ChromeMobile": "7177.498437391487"}}
{"another.com": {"MobileSafari": "6237.433155080214"}}
{"another.com": {"Safari": "5895.409403430795"}}
```

and I want to merge into one JSON file

```json
[
  {
    "domain.com": {
      "Chrome": "19362.344607264396"
    }
  },
  {
    "domain.com": {
      "ChromeMobile": "7177.498437391487"
    }
  },
  {
    "another.com": {
      "MobileSafari": "6237.433155080214"
    }
  },
  {
    "another.com": {
      "Safari": "5895.409403430795"
    }
  }
]
```

or ideally to have a JSON likes to this

```json
{
  "browsers": [
    {
      "domain.com": {
        "Chrome": "19362.344607264396",
        "ChromeMobile": "7177.498437391487",
      },
      "another.com": {
        "MobileSafari": "6237.433155080214",
        "Safari": "5895.409403430795"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My code

```py
# Cloudflare zone bandwidth total
def browser_map_page_views(domain_zone):
    cloudflare = prom.custom_query(
        query="topk(5, sum by(family) (increase(browser_map_page_views_count{job='cloudflare', zone='"f'{domain_zone}'"'}[10d])))"
    )
    for domain_z in cloudflare:
        user_agent = domain_z['metric']['family']
        value = domain_z['value'][1]
        yield {domain_zone: {user_agent: {'value': value}}}
```

```py
# Get list of zones from Prometheus based on Host Tracker data
def domain_zones():
    zones_domain = prom.custom_query(
        query="host_tracker_uptime_percent{job='donodeexporter'}"
    )
    for domain_z in zones_domain:
        yield domain_z['metric']['zone']
```

There is a final output.

```py
# Get a list of domains and substitution each one into a request of Prometheus query.
for domain_list in domain_zones():
    for dict in browser_map_page_views(domain_zone=domain_list):
        dicts = dict
        print(json.dumps(dicts))
```

Comment: What is your question about this?

Comment: I have edited the question. How to merge strings from the yield generator of JSON into one JSON?

Comment: Instead of using `json.dumps` for each `dict` right away, why don't you append them all to a new list first and call `json.dumps` on that list at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
import json


DATA = [
    {"domain.com": {"Chrome": "19362.344607264396"}},
    {"domain.com": {"ChromeMobile": "7177.498437391487"}},
    {"another.com": {"MobileSafari": "6237.433155080214"}},
    {"another.com": {"Safari": "5895.409403430795"}}
]


def yield_data():
    for d in DATA:
        yield d


def merge1():
    return list(yield_data())


def merge2():
    output = {}
    for d in DATA:
        key = list(d.keys())[0]
        output[key] = output.get(key, {})
        output[key].update(d[key])
    
    return {"browsers": [output]}


print(json.dumps(merge1(), indent=2))
print(json.dumps(merge2(), indent=2))
```

`merge1`'s output looks like:

```
[
  {
    "domain.com": {
      "Chrome": "19362.344607264396"
    }
  },
  {
    "domain.com": {
      "ChromeMobile": "7177.498437391487"
    }
  },
  {
    "another.com": {
      "MobileSafari": "6237.433155080214"
    }
  },
  {
    "another.com": {
      "Safari": "5895.409403430795"
    }
  }
]
```

`merge2`'s output looks like

```
{
  "browsers": [
    {
      "domain.com": {
        "Chrome": "19362.344607264396",
        "ChromeMobile": "7177.498437391487"
      },
      "another.com": {
        "MobileSafari": "6237.433155080214",
        "Safari": "5895.409403430795"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your examples work well. However, in my case, the second `merge2` is more complicated. Could you help with this, please?

https://gist.github.com/rmalenko/9fca34959efdde488c5d3eb9679f2e79